# Background process multiplying itself multiple times on a VPS

Tags: php, vps

I uploaded my php file to a VPS then launched it via domain name and it looks like that php process multiplies itself multiple times.

Basically this php process scrapes data from a chatting site and then performs various tasks with it. Then it writes in a `.txt` file and it has an infinite loop in it.

It works absolutely well in my pc (localhost using WAMP server).

So here is top code of php file.

```
if(!isset($_GET["pass"]))
{
    exit();
}
if($_GET["pass"] != "MY_PASS_HERE")exit();//to make php file protected so that i can start it only

ignore_user_abort(true); 
set_time_limit(0);
```

To understand exactly what is happening I uploaded logs obtained by localhost and VPS on pastebin.

[Normal Logs(localhost)](http://pastebin.com/YFcDzBBQ)

[VPS logs](http://pastebin.com/pmiS89JG)

"Writing began At" line is only written once in script, before the infinite loop. But as you see in VPS logs that "Writing began At" lines is appearing frequently but I started the process only once.

And you can also see in VPS logs that chat lines begin to multiply as we move down.

PS. I lauched the process like this : `my_domain_name.com/process.php?pass=MY_PASS_HERE` and only once but then too it multiplies itself.

EDIT:
My php structure is like this

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["pass"]))
    {
        exit();
    }
    if($_GET["pass"] != "MY_PASS_HERE")exit();//to make php file protected so that i can start it only
    
    ignore_user_abort(true); 
//connect to mysql database here
//initialize libcurl with options here
//open log file
while(!file_exists("kill.txt"))//this is to break loop when kill.txt file is created
{
//scraping chat and writing to log at end of loop
}//end of loop
//closing mysql libcurl and file here
?>
```

Comment: The header of your file will not help. Please post all relevant parts of the code and the logs in the question itself. You might want to consult the FAQ on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @h7r problem is not with code, it works perfectly on localhost but same script if ran on VPS do what I have told. The problem is that process is multiplying it self automatically even though i opened it one time only

Comment: This might be true. But please add the relevant data to the question. Don't link to an external site.

Comment: @h7r I edited code look at it

Comment: You are not providing enough information, specially the relevant parts inside the `while` block. If you really believe that the issue is not with your code, but your hosting instead, you need to provide further evindence of this too. Please do read about how to provide a complete example as I have already pointed out, otherwise hardly someone will be able to help.

Comment: It was VPS I tried other VPS and then problem solved.. thanks for your time h7r